# Can't Authorize Facebook in Gwibber

Tags: gwibber, facebook

Whenever I try to add Facebook account in Gwibber, It gives the following error:

```
**Unable to load page**

Problem occurred while loading the URL https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?scope=publish_stream%2Cread_stream%2Cstatus_update%2Coffline_access%2Cuser_photos%2Cfriends_photos&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&type=user_agent&display=popup&client_id=71b85c6d8cb5bbb9f1a3f8bbdcdd4b05

**Cannot resolve proxy hostname ()**
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I got your problem now. Try this few steps:

1. Go to **Home** folder, then show all hidden files using `Ctrl+H`.
2. Browse to **.config/gwibber**.
3. Delete **gwibber.sqlite**.
4. Now try to connect your Facebook.

Comment: Yes My internet is working very well. I even Authorized Twitter successfully. The only problem is in Facebook Authorization. Could you please help me out in fixing Proxy setting?

Comment: @Ashish I see. I updated my answer. Does it work?

Comment: Done. But it Didn't helped. And Bytheway I just removed the twitter account and tried authorizing again and found the same problem in that as well.

Comment: Really? Did you try updating your software? Or re-install Gwibber?

Comment: I did tried Updating it and even tried installing it without pluggins because I somewhere read that "telepathy-butterfly" creates problem. But nothing is working out

Comment: I see. Do Empathy works well for you, or having a same problem? I mean, it also uses authorization, I wonder if it's work or not.

Comment: Exactly! It's also not working!! Except the Yahoo account! It do not connect with a message "No Reason Specified"

Comment: Okay, so you're having a third-party authorization problem here. But why it's not affecting the Yahoo! account, I wonder? Did you try restarting your system?

Comment: Yes, Tried it many times.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did:

According to [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/+bug/259830):

> Currently gwibber seems to expect a direct connection to the net, no
>   use of a proxy. Gwibber should really query gnome for proxy
>   information and use it for connecting to the net. You could also
>   consider using libproxy.

So I went to

> System Settings > Network > Network Proxy

and selected "None" in the "Method" box, instead of Automatic or Manual. Then applied it system wide and ta-da! Gwibber now works.

Hope I helped!

EDIT: Added a screenshot for reference
[image: image for reference]

Answer (score 0):

Have you set phone verification for your facebook? If yes please turn it off 1st. Login to Gwibber, and turn back your phone verification on facebook.

Comment: Yes, It's currently on. I switched it off now and tried again. But it's not working out. Gwibber is unable to even open the login page, then how can it communicate with my account?

Comment: Please Turn it OFF an login your Facebook from Gwibber.

Comment: Does this post help you @Ashish ?

Comment: Nopes :( No improvement.

Comment: Did you turn it off before login to Gwibber? If still cant login im sorry Sir. Because in my case, phone verification is the issue. But your's im not sure.

Comment: Yeah i did turned it off. No problem

Comment: How do ya turn them off I am having this same issue...if this worked for you I would like to know how to turn them off

Comment: First off [Login Approvals](http://i.imgur.com/AlknF.png) or create [Apps Password](http://i.imgur.com/ecVHi.png)

Comment: Thank you penreturn it didn't work for me still unable to get facebook up and running via gwibber

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: http://ubuntuguide.net/ubuntu-tip-12-04-midori-epiphany-cannot-resolve-proxy-hostname-problem

Here is the important part:

> Head to System Settings -> Network, in Network Proxy tab set Proxy
>   Method to None and click “Apply system wide”.

Hope this will help!